# How do i get farmers to replant what i want to have them replant

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So farmers will replant seeds when they harvest their crop but how do i make them replant what i want them to replant. Say they,re replanting with wheat seeds but i want them to replant with beetroot seeds how do i get them to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw the beetroot seeds at them if you want beetroots. If the villager picks them up he can plant it.